# Android - Structure of classes for DB Tables + POJO Class can be same?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-contentprovider, android-database

I have 25+ tables and I have used **Content Provider** with Database.

I have created separate files for each tables with following structure:

- **TProductUnit.java** in package of **com.myapp.db.tables**

  ```
  public class TProductUnit {

      /***
       * Fields of TABLE_PRODUCT_UNIT Table
       ***/
      public static final String TABLE_PRODUCT_UNIT = "product_unit";
      /**
       * Columns of TABLE_PRODUCT_UNIT
       */
      public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_SERVER_ID = "id";
      public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_NAME = "name";
      public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_ITP = "itp";
      public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_UTP = "utp";
      public static final String PRODUCT_UNIT_STATUS = "status";

      public static String[] PRODUCT_UNIT_COLUMNS = new String[] {
              BaseColumns._ID,
              PRODUCT_UNIT_SERVER_ID,
              PRODUCT_UNIT_NAME,
              PRODUCT_UNIT_ITP,
              PRODUCT_UNIT_UTP,
              PRODUCT_UNIT_STATUS
      };
  }
  ```
- **ProductUnit.java** is **POJO class** which will helpful when First time get data from Server.

  ```
  public class ProductUnit {

          @SerializedName("id")
          @Expose
          private Integer id;
          @SerializedName("product_id")
          @Expose
          private Integer productId;
          @SerializedName("url")
          @Expose
          private String url;
          @SerializedName("bit")
          @Expose
          private int bit;
          @SerializedName("status")
          @Expose
          private Integer status;
          @SerializedName("itp")
          @Expose
          private String itp;
          @SerializedName("utp")
          @Expose
          private String utp;

          /**
           * @return The id
           */
          public Integer getId() {
              return id;
          }

          /**
           * @param id The id
           */
          public void setId(Integer id) {
              this.id = id;
          }

          public Integer getProductId() {
              return productId;
          }

          public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
              this.productId = productId;
          }

          public int getBit() {
              return bit;
          }

          public void setBit(int bit) {
              this.bit = bit;
          }

          public String getUrl() {
              return url;
          }

          public void setUrl(String url) {
              this.url = url;
          }

          /**
           * @return The status
           */
          public Integer getStatus() {
              return status;
          }

          /**
           * @param status The status
           */
          public void setStatus(Integer status) {
              this.status = status;
          }

          /**
           * @return The itp
           */
          public String getItp() {
              return itp;
          }

          /**
           * @param itp The itp
           */
          public void setItp(String itp) {
              this.itp = itp;
          }

          /**
           * @return The utp
           */
          public String getUtp() {
              return utp;
          }

          /**
           * @param utp The utp
           */
          public void setUtp(String utp) {
              this.utp = utp;
          }

          /**
           * Convenient method to get the objects data members in ContentValues object.
           * This will be useful for Content Provider operations,
           * which use ContentValues object to represent the data.
           *
           * @return
           */
          public ContentValues getContentValues() {
              ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

              values.put(PRODUCT_UNIT_SERVER_ID, id);
              values.put(PRODUCT_UNIT_NAME, name);
              values.put(PRODUCT_UNIT_ITP, itp);
              values.put(PRODUCT_UNIT_UTP, utp);
              values.put(PRODUCT_UNIT_STATUS, status);

              return values;
          }
  }
  ```

Both classes have most of the same number of fields with same values if we think about  `@SerializedName`

**Problem:**

1. Whenever I need to add some fields in any Particular Table then I have to add in all Table file and JSON POJO Class too.
2. When any field name changed by server side then I have to change in both file.

**My Question is:** Is there any better solution for this optimization. Have you ever manage like this?

P.S. I have 25+ tables so I have to create 50+ classes.

Help please. Thanks.

Comment: Probably observer design pattern can be implemented. http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java

Comment: Use a ORM package so you can just have one model class that also handles the database side.  GreenDao, Realm, ActiveAndroid, etc.